# how to show an object's type in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, types

For debug use I want to show the type of a variable in Google App Engine.

In traditional environment, I will use `"print type( x )"` to do it. But in GAE I just don't know why I can't use `self.response.out.write( str( type( x )  )  )` to echo it in the browser. I got confused because I did transform the `<type 'type'>` to `< type 'str' >`.
Since that doesn't work I have to use `self.response.out.write( str( type( x) == type( "123" )  ) )` instead of directly echoing the type.

So what did I miss in thinking?

I am also using logging module to echo the type which works well. But I still want to know why `self.response.out.write(  )` doesn't work.

Thanks all for help!!

Comment: What does `self.response.out.write( str( type( x ) ) )` display for you?

Comment: Nothing. What confused me is that the operation echo nothing just like str() generates a "" string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When browser renders html it thinks that `<type 'str'>` is a (unknown) tag, so it renders it as `<type 'str'></type>`, hence it becomes part of your page markup... You can see this with Firebug or any similar tool.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Accoring to your tips I've found the code such as <type 'int'> in the page source. So stupid am I forgetting checking the page source and just being wandering arround